# TColorBox and Tikz, arrows are not on the diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

Below I have included a mwe. As you can see, in the last diagram, the errors for the last three boxes are rendering onto the next page. How can I fix this? I compile using TexShop which uses this command `pdftex --file-line-error --synctex=1`. Yes, I have compiled more than twice.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem, amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 125]{microtype}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[skins, raster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{optics}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% force LaTeX to write the author, title, and copyright into the PDF
\makeatletter
  \AtEndDocument{\hyxmp@find@metadata\hyxmp@embed@packet}
\makeatother
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linkcolor=part,
    draft=false,
    pdfauthor={some authoer},
    pdftitle={some org},
    pdfcopyright={Copyright \copyright~2019 by author. Some rights reserved.},
    pdfpagelabels=true,
    implicit=false
}

\chapterstyle{ell}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{6pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\linespread{1.3}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   The Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}
\date{}
\maketitle

\frontmatter

\blindtext

\mainmatter

\Blindtext
\tcbset{enhanced, nobeforeafter, sidebyside align=top,box align=center, width=1.6in}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=one]
Something happens
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=two]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=three]
Many more somethings happen and the world nearly dies
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=four]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=five]
Something happens
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=six]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=0.5mm]
\draw[->] (one.east) to (two.west);
\draw[->] (three.east) to (four.west);
\draw[->] (five.east) to (six.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\blindtext
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=1]
Something happens
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=2]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=3]
Something happens
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=4]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=5]
Something happens
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=6]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=0.5mm]
\draw[->] (1.east) to (2.west);
\draw[->] (3.east) to (4.west);
\draw[->] (5.east) to (6.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\backmatter

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: arrows are not on the diagram]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just place the tikzpicture in the same `center` environment to force it to be in the same page ... LaTeX decided to place the colorbox in the next page but changed its mind and forced that after second thought in the previous ... tikz picture was outside the environment and didn't followed the second thought of LaTeX because it is printed after the second internal compilation (needs one more than a real tikzpicture as an overlay)... Hope that helped.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem, amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 125]{microtype}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[skins, raster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{optics}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% force LaTeX to write the author, title, and copyright into the PDF
\makeatletter
  \AtEndDocument{\hyxmp@find@metadata\hyxmp@embed@packet}
\makeatother
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linkcolor=part,
    draft=false,
    pdfauthor={some authoer},
    pdftitle={some org},
    pdfcopyright={Copyright \copyright~2019 by author. Some rights reserved.},
    pdfpagelabels=true,
    implicit=false
}

\chapterstyle{ell}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{6pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\linespread{1.3}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   The Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}
\date{}
\maketitle

\frontmatter

\blindtext

\mainmatter

\Blindtext
\tcbset{enhanced, nobeforeafter, sidebyside align=top,box align=center, width=1.6in}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=one]
Something happens
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=two]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=three]
Many more somethings happen and the world nearly dies
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=four]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=five]
Something happens
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=six]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=0.5mm]
\draw[->] (one.east) to (two.west);
\draw[->] (three.east) to (four.west);
\draw[->] (five.east) to (six.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\blindtext
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=1]
Something happens
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=2]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=3]
Something happens
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=4]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=5]
Something happens
\end{tcolorbox}
\qquad
\begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=6]
a result
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=0.5mm]
\draw[->] (1.east) to (2.west);
\draw[->] (3.east) to (4.west);
\draw[->] (5.east) to (6.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\backmatter

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, thank you, king stranger. I've been going insane for about two weeks trying to figure out what to do. That had never even occurred to me.

Comment: Welcome ... it is somehow strange ... but if you see that the overlay pictures are printed after one more compilation (compile without help tools from command line) you can imagine this ... This is a reason to use command line compilation at least some times :)